# How can I restore my data in the svn?

Tags: svn, commit, restore

I use the **svn** to control my project.But today,I **update** the repository before **commit**,and then I **revert** the project.Now,I cann't **restore** my project.
How can I **restore** my project?

Comment: is there an error you see. provide more details on the exact problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, after `revert` you can't go back. 
 If you don't have some local backup then the changes you made are lost, sorry.

Comment: there is no anyway?my god.

Comment: Well, if some file was *new* and *added*, then it is not lost, just changed it's status to *?*. When you use `TortoiseSVN`, revert is sending files to recycle bin, but that is not the case with the command line client.